# How can I have URL which contains the id of object?

Tags: url, parameters, struts

How can I have a URL in Struts which contains the `id` of an object and then pass it to an action to show the object by this `id`? e.g. the URL is `/users/1` and it shows a `user` object which has the `id =1`.

Comment: How about a url like  `/users/find_user.do?id=1` and then getting the `id` value in the action?

Comment: However it seems easier to implement, I would not like this way

Comment: It's no more or less difficult than putting it in the URL. All of this is covered in the S2 tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

To have parameters as a part of the path of the URL you should use an action mapper which is able to parse them when a request is processed by Struts.

In Struts you can find different action mapper implemented classes.